# Azure AD Directory Services Domain Name Guideline

Tags: azure-active-directory

When configuring Azure AD directory services, we would like to use the name "xxx.com".  "xxx.com" is not publicly owned by us and we cannot acquire it.

Does anyone foresee any issues with us using this name when configuring the DNS domain name for AD directory services or should we only specify a domain name that we can control public DNS records for?

Also should the domain we specify match one of the custom domains that we have added to custom domain list in Azure AD?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose "xxx.com" you mentioned is the initial domain name in the form of `domainname.onmicrosoft.com` which is also the primary domain name. The initial domain name cannot be changed or deleted, but you can add your custom domain name to Azure AD as well.

You can select any custom domain name which can be verified in Azure AD. The domain you specify should match one of the custom domains that you have added to custom domain list in Azure AD. Also, If you want to add a third-level domain name such as `domainname.contoso.com` to your directory, you should first add and verify the second-level domain, such as contoso.com. The subdomain will be automatically verified by Azure AD.

> If you plan to federate your on-premises Windows Server AD with Azure
>   AD, then you need to select the **I plan to configure this domain for
>   single sign-on with my local Active Directory** checkbox when you run
>   the Azure AD Connect tool to synchronize your directories. You also
>   need to register the same domain name you select for federating with
>   your on-premises directory in the Azure AD Domain step in the wizard.

Reference: [Add a custom domain name to Azure Active Directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/add-custom-domain)

Comment: OK...would that explain why I cannot join an Azure VM to our domain when using a cloud based account where the domain does not match the cloud account.  For example.  We have a verified custom domain called "domain1.com" and have a managed user account called "admin@domain1.com" which is a global directory admin.  The domain name we used when creating AD Services is "domain2.com".  When trying  to domain join an azure VM, we specify "domain2.com\admin@domain1.com" (with the password), but it always indicates bad user name and password.

Comment: @Geekn, firstly, the account you use to join a domain should be a UPN format or a SAMAccountName format referring to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-domain-services/active-directory-ds-getting-started-admingroup), then you need the credentials of a user account belonging to the 'AAD DC Administrators' group in your directory, to [administer your managed domain.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-domain-services/active-directory-ds-admin-guide-administer-domain)